# SalesForce Report, to return contacts who have attended 3+ Campaigns

Tags: reporting, formula

I really need some help

Aim- Only show contacts where they have attended 3 or more campaigns. 
i have built the following report (see attached image) but i am stuck on how i can return contacts who have "Member Status" = Attended and that count is greater than 3

[image: Report]

Report type  : Campaign with contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't rollup from the campaign to the contact, you will probably need to create a trigger on campaign to update the contact record with # of campaigns attended.